# How to delete user and node, drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a module which adds a new node(with user info) if a user is added. Now I want to implement a **user_delete** hook that deletes the node if the user is deleted. I don't know how to implement this.

This code adds a new node for new user:

```
function user_profile_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {

    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'members';
    node_object_prepare($node);

    //dvm($account);
    $node->title = $account->name;

    $user_info = user_load($account->uid);

    $node->field_user["und"][0]["uid"] = $account->uid;


    $path = $account->name;

    $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

    node_save($node);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
function node_delete($nid) {
 node_delete_multiple(array($nid));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for user you can use

[user_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_delete/7) where you pass the `$uid` as the parameter

as for nodes there is [node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) you pass you pass the `$nid` as the parameter.

also deleting nodes based on user id there is this function [node_user_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_user_delete/7)

Answer (score 0):

Until I solved the user reg spam problem with the stop_spam_reg module, I routinely purged the spam accounts like this:

/devel/php

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u') ->fields('u', array('uid'));
$result = $query->execute();
foreach ($result as $record) {
    if( $record->uid>1){  //replace 1 with the latest valid uid you want to keep 
    user_delete($record->uid);
    }
}
```

Be careful to leave user 1 or you'll have bigger issues than spam users :)